# docker push error "denied: requested access to the resource is denied"

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

This error occurs when trying to push an image to the public repository on **Docker Hub**. There have been no issues with other registries I have tried.

*I have looked at numerous sites, blogs including StackOverflow and there is still no clear answer.*

You can try to replicate this issue as follows.

[image: Image on local host]

As shown in the screenshot above, I have an image `aspc-mvc-app` on local docker host. As shown, it has 3 tags - `1.0.5`, `1.0.5.latest` and `latest`.

**Assume that we are trying to push using an account name of `janedoe` at Docker Hub**

Per documentation on [Docker.io](https://docs.docker.com/docker-cloud/builds/push-images/) and numerous other sites, there are 3 steps to pushing.

*(1) Login*

```
docker login "index.docker.io" -u janedoe -p <password>
```

--> I get `Login Succeeded` which is good!

*(2) Add one or more tags*

Of the 3 tags, let's just tag the `latest`.

```
docker tag janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest janedoe/aspc-mvc-app
```

--> The prompt returns with no error. So far so good.

*(3) Push*

```
docker push janedoe/aspc-mvc-app
```

--> This is where the error occurs.

As shown on the screenshot below, initial checks seem to occur fine until you get the error *denied: requested access to the resource is denied*

[image]

At step (2), I have tried numerous other formats including the following.

```
docker tag janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest
docker tag janedoe/aspc-mvc-app janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest

docker tag aspc-mvc-app:latest janedoe/aspc-mvc-app
docker tag aspc-mvc-app janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest

docker tag 306a8fd79d88 janedoe/aspc-mvc-app
docker tag 306a8fd79d88 janedoe/aspc-mvc-app:latest
```

All fail with the same error.

As a comparison, with the same exact image, I had no problem pushing to Azure Container Registry.

Since Docker Hub is so popular, can anyone shed light on what the mystery is, or if there is a detailed documentation anywhere?

**Updated 5/9/2017**

I am fairly up-to-date on docker cli and server versions. Right now, my cli is `17.05.0-ce-rc1` and server is `17.04.0-ce` as shown below.

[image]

Comment: What version of Docker? You shouldn't need to `docker login "index.docker.io"` just `docker login`.

Comment: update docker to the latest version, restart the docker service and try again.

Comment: Of all the places I thought things could have gone wrong, it was the login part as Andy Shinn had suggested. The fact that we still get `Login Succeeded` with `index.docker.io` is confusing and Docker Hub should respond with a warning IMO. Anyways, thanks a lot Andy, problem solved :)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The solution is simply to change the way of logging in at step (1).

```
docker login -u janedoe -p <password>
```

Everything else can stay the way described above. The image was successfully pushed to Docker Hub!

Comment: This solution worked for me. It appears that when using to the default docker registry, you must omit the HOST parameter. (Trying to explicitly provide "docker.io" as the HOST param is what sent me down this rabbit hole).

Comment: If it still does not work, try removing the file - "~/.docker/config.json" and restart the docker service - "service docker restart". Now re-login omitting docker-hub url as above.

Comment: This works, but this is so increadibly dumb, this literally wasted 4 hours of my life.

Comment: Use --password-stdin instead of -p to be more secure

Comment: it's so bizarre that this solves the issue; this should count as a bug (no reason for one of two equivalent methods to fail)

Answer (score 27):

1. First login by typing `sudo docker login` in the terminal. Enter username and password
2. Visit your docker account and create a new repository. In my case I created a repository **crabigator1900/dockerhub**
3. Say you have a docker image with repository name:**crabigator/django** and tag:**latest**.

In that case you will need to tag this image with a label of your wish. I decided to tag it with the label:**myfirstimagepush**. You tag the image by typing the command

`sudo docker tag crabigator/django:latest crabigator1900/dockerhub:firstimagepush`

4. Finally push the image to your repo using the command

`sudo docker push crabigator1900/dockerhub:firstimagepush`

That's all there is to it.

Comment: you shouldn't be using sudo

Comment: this works but yes, dont use sudo for everything. just run the commands without sudo and you are good to go.

Comment: @CarlosPliego shh if it works it works

Answer (score 12):

I too had the same issue, but after trying some combinations this worked.

Whenever you push - that refers to **docker.io/** followed by registry path.

In my case my username is **rushmith** and I created a sample repository called **docker** under rushmith.

My link is : **"hub.docker.com/r/rushmith/docker/"**

Now I created a tag to my image that I want to push as: **rushmith/docker**

And It worked successfully.

**`$ docker login -u rushmith`**

(Give the password then type as below)

**`$ docker push rushmith/docker:latest`**

**Output:**

```
The push refers to a repository [docker.io/rushmith/docker]
7fbb0e1e64cb: Pushed
33f1a94ed7fc: Pushed 
b27287a6dbce: Pushed 
47c2386f248c: Pushed 
2be95f0d8a0c: Pushed 
2df9b8def18a: Pushed 
latest: digest: 
sha256:4d749d86b4a2d9304a50df474f6236140dc2d169b9aabc354cdbc6ac107390f2 size: 1569
```

Comment: That is good to know that by default, `docker push` refers to the `docker.io` repo

Answer (score 12):

I hope this late solution might help someone.
The reason of this error message was you **haven't named your images properly**.
Let say your account name on docker.io was `your-name` then your new repo name is going to be `your-name/your-new-image-name`.

In order to push your image, first you have to tag (name) your local images as:

```
docker tag local-image[:tag-name] your-name/your-new-image-name[:tag-name]
```

Things in the brackets is optional. You may want to check the result with `docker image ls`. Then let push your image to your docker repo:

```
docker push your-name/your-new-image-name[:tag-name]
```

Done! Your image was pushed to docker repos.

Answer (score 6):

First you need to ensure you have logged into your account

[image]

You need to create a repository, below is the command to create a repository -

docker tag local-image:tagname **YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME**/tagname

docker push **YOUR-ACCOUNT-NAME**/tagname
[image]

Comment: That worked for me!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the following steps:

**Step 1:** `docker login -u <username> -p <password>`

A message with "Login Succeeded" will appear, confirming your successful login.

**Step 2:**
Now in order to push the image just make sure the path which you are using must have your username included in the tag.

e.g: Suppose link is: **"hub.docker.com/u/xyz/"** 
Create a tag to image as **docker push xyz/docker:latest**.

If you already have some different tag change it using command

```
docker tag <old tag> <new tag>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

after 1 hour's struggling with different ways mentioned above,
I reinstalled the neweast version of Docker Desktop app in my mbp, then it is solved.

the neweast version is 20.10.2
and the old version is 17.x, which was installed 5 years ago.

Comment: same, if you have tried everything else, same commands as on SO suggestions and no luck, just update your docker. (before update, login was successful on command line, but not on the mack docker UI, might be a good hint an upgrade is needed)

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue
My Docker version is 24.x.x

```
docker login -u username

docker tag image_name username/image_name:v1

docker push username/image_name:v1
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a repository from a website.

It possible that you don't have a permission for creating repository.

Answer (score 0):

docker push does not create a repo name so if not present it says access not available

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
> docker login -u janedoe
Password:
Login Succeeded 

> docker tag myapp:0.0.1 janedoe/myflinkapp:0.0.1

> docker push janedoe/myapp:0.0.1
The push refers to repository [docker.io/janedoe/myapp]
b763be657a2c: Pushed
e534dae385a8: Pushed
5af3d5d57035: Pushed
0e44828b51e2: Pushed
fdd771f27095: Pushed
ef9a7b8862f4: Pushed
a1f2f42922b1: Pushed
4762552ad7d8: Pushed
0.0.1: digest: sha256:0069ee2c39b422e64f0493d2b2e9cbe7736a size: 2154
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was facing this issue even after logging into Docker registry successfully.

So, I tried running the docker push as sudo and it worked.

Make sure you follow these steps:

1. Run `docker login`
2. After logging in successfully, run the docker push command
3. If the push failed, run this: `sudo docker push repoName:tagName`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 2FA and run

```
docker login -u <your_docker_user_name>
```

you will get `Login successful` but you won't be able to push.

This is because you're using 2FA which requires one-time password to login into your account.

To be able to push with 2FA enabled you need to use an access token. To generate one go to `Account settings/Security` on [Docker Hub website](https://hub.docker.com/) and click `New Access Token`. As of `Access Permissions` preferably choose `Read & Write` - this is the entry level for being able to push. Only generate `Read, Write, Delete` token if you really need it!

You'll be prompted with instructions on what to do next. Just to keep the answer full, you'll have to run

```
docker login -u <you_docker_username>
```

and when prompted for `Password` paste your `Personal Access Token`.

IMPORTANT: save your `Personal Access Token` in a password manager and never share with anyone and never push to github or add to your source code. NEVER! Please.

Now, when you run `docker push <your_docker_username>/<your_docker_repo_name>:<tag_of_your_image>` you should be able to push the image to the Docker Hub.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue and I found out my login url are different with the push url, this is the login url:

```
docker login --username=jiangchaoquan registry.cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com
```

and this is the push url:

```
docker push registry.cn-shanghai.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/rust-musl-builder:1.0.0
```

do not make this mistake.

Answer (score -3):

I have the same problem and it was solved by running the push command with sudo. I think it is only a privilege problem.

```
sudo docker push janedoe/aspc-mvc-app
```