# Why can't push the new created image into docker-hub?

Tags: docker, push

I want to create my own image and push it into my docker-hub.

Prepare:

```
mkdir /tmp/mydebian
cd  /tmp/mydebian
vim  mydebian.Dockerfile
#all contents omitted here
```

Build the image with Dockerfile:

```
docker build -f mydebian.Dockerfile --tag=mydebian:0.0.1 .
```

Check it:

```
docker images
REPOSITORY            TAG        IMAGE ID       CREATED         SIZE
mydebian              0.0.1      bd66705654b1   5 minutes ago   460MB
```

Login docker:

```
docker login -u "myusername" -p "xxxxxxxx" docker.io
```

Push now:

```
docker push myusername/mydebian:0.0.1
The push refers to repository [docker.io/myusername/mydebian]
An image does not exist locally with the tag: myusername/mydebian
```

Try other format:

```
docker push mydebian:0.0.1
The push refers to repository [docker.io/library/mydebian]
690c901c038e: Preparing 
1155352a0b68: Preparing 
1201adb8bea9: Preparing 
a13c519c6361: Preparing 
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

How can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tag your images with the name they'll be pushed with. Either on build:

```
docker build -f mydebian.Dockerfile --tag=myusername/mydebian:0.0.1 .
```

Or to give an existing image an additional tag:

```
docker tag mydebian:0.0.1 myusername/mydebian:0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Leave out the docker.io in the end for the login command. Like this:

```
docker login -u "myusername" -p "xxxxxxxx"
```

[Same error with a longer description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43858398/docker-push-error-denied-requested-access-to-the-resource-is-denied#43862114)